# Using dialogs in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols

What if at some moment of time I need to get user input by calling dialog window or something like that. What is the best way to implement this using QML? Any analogs of `prompt` in js?

Comment: Are you targeting desktops, phones, or iPad type devices?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question but I think one of the approaches using a Loader will work.  http://qt-project.org/wiki/QML-Application-Structuring-Approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Dialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#details), available **since Qt 5.3**, and customize it as you wish.
*Ensure, that you have this version installed and working.*

[Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtquickdialogs-systemdialogs-customdialogs-qml.html) you can find example.

Also, take a look at small example I've prepared:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("Custom Dialog")

    Dialog {
        id: customDialog
        title: "Custom Dialog in QML/Qt 5.3"
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text {
                text: "Here goes all your custom elements..."
            }
            TextInput {
                id: edtInput
                text: "Input text"
            }
        }

        onButtonClicked: {
            if (clickedButton==StandardButton.Ok) {
                console.log("Accepted " + clickedButton)
                lblResults.text += edtInput.text
            } else {
                console.log("Rejected" + clickedButton)
            }
        }
    }
    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Call Custom dialog")
            onClicked: customDialog.open()
        }

        Text {
            id: lblResults
            text: qsTr("Results: ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the dialog component was available even before 5.3, albeit in experimental state. See the line at the top `Since: Qt 5.2`.

Comment: Example link is dead. https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/texmaker_v5.0.2/qt57/doc/qtquickdialogs/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html works

Comment: @PΞDROLUZ thanks for noting it. Already updated links.